# Trying to link to a page, but cannot find a unique link

Tags: javascript, html

I am using a Learning Management System that uses JavaScript. I want to link to a specific page, but each page in a module has the same URL. When I use that URL, it directs me to the last page I visited.

I looked at the source code and added an ID at the end of the URL, but it still takes me back to the last page I visited.

This is the source code I used.

```
<li id="D2L_LE_Content_TreeBrowser_D2L.LE.Content.ContentObject.ModuleCO-
2006" data-key="D2L.LE.Content.ContentObject.ModuleCO-2006" class="d2l-le-
TreeAccordionItem d2l-le-TreeAccordionItem-Root"><a class="d2l-le-
TreeAccordionItem-anchor vui-heading-4 d2l-filedrop" 
href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="D2L.O(&quot;__g1&quot;,23)();" 
id="d2l_1_795_680">
<div class="d2l-le-TreeAccordionItem-wrapper d2l-body-
compact">
```

I pulled the module number and put it at the end of this [URL](https://cuped.brightspace.com/d2l/le/content/6665/HomeitemIdentifier=D2L.LContent.ContentObj%C2%ADect.ModuleCO-2006):

How to I create a specific URL for that page, so I can link directly to it?

Thanks